# Compute 'not ready' when deploying custom environment in promptflow

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-promptflow

I'm trying to create a runtime to use for the new prompt flow feature. I'm trying to use a custom environment for the runtime because I need additional python packages.The environment builds without issue. However, when I try to create a runtime it always throws this error. I've tried several times to with different compute instances without success.

This is the error I recieved:

```
UserError: FlowRuntime test in compute instance lms-prompt-flow-gb compute is not ready: runtime starting timeout. Please try to create a new compute instance to hold runtime
```

Can anyone please help me debug this error?

[image: error]

compute instance details I used :
Standard_E8s_v3
8 cores, 64GB RAM, 128GB storage
100 cores
Memory optimized

Following is the conda.yml of environment:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - pip=23.3.1
  - pip:
      - aiohttp==3.8.6
      - aiosignal==1.3.1
      - annotated-types==0.6.0
      - anyio==3.7.1
      - async-timeout==4.0.3
      - attrs==23.1.0
      - azure-core==1.29.4
      - azure-functions==1.17.0
      - azure-functions-durable==1.2.6
      - azure-storage-blob==12.18.3
      - beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
      - certifi==2023.7.22
      - cffi==1.16.0
      - charset-normalizer==3.3.0
      - colorama==0.4.6
      - cryptography==41.0.4
      - dataclasses-json==0.6.1
      - exceptiongroup==1.1.3
      - filelock==3.12.4
      - frozenlist==1.4.0
      - furl==2.1.3
      - gdown==4.7.1
      - greenlet==3.0.0
      - idna==3.4
      - isodate==0.6.1
      - jsonpatch==1.33
      - jsonpointer==2.4
      - langchain==0.0.315
      - langsmith==0.0.43
      - marshmallow==3.20.1
      - multidict==6.0.4
      - mypy-extensions==1.0.0
      - numpy==1.26.1
      - openai==0.28.1
      - orderedmultidict==1.0.1
      - packaging==23.2
      - pycparser==2.21
      - pydantic==2.4.2
      - pydantic_core==2.10.1
      - PySocks==1.7.1
      - python-dateutil==2.8.2
      - PyYAML==6.0.1
      - requests==2.31.0
      - six==1.16.0
      - sniffio==1.3.0
      - soupsieve==2.5
      - SQLAlchemy==2.0.22
      - tenacity==8.2.3
      - tqdm==4.66.1
      - typing-inspect==0.9.0
      - typing_extensions==4.8.0
      - urllib3==2.0.6
      - yarl==1.9.2
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.